# Sharing single base object across multiple instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

In my API design, I have something like this:

```py
class APIConnection:
    # sets up the session and only contains connection-related methods
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def api_call(self):
        # do session-related stuff


class User(APIConnection):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        super().__init__()
        # do login stuff, get access token
        # update inherited session with authorization headers
        self.session.headers.update({"Access-Token": access_token})

        self.profile = Profile(profile_data) # set up profile object

class Profile:
    def __init__(self, profile_data):
        pass

    # this is where I would like to get access to the session that User inherited from APIConnection
    # so that I might call Profile-related functions like this through composition

    def edit_profile(self):
        self.api_call()

    def remove_avatar(self):
        self.api_call()


# My endgoal is so the user can write stuff like:
user = User("username", "password")
user.profile.edit_profile()
user.profile.remove_avatar()
# which would only be possible if Profile could share the APIConnection object that User created
```

I am new to OO programming and cannot think of a clean way to do this.

I would like for the `Profile` instance that `User` created to also get access to the inherited `APIConnection` without having to re-create it or do anything weird.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you need to pass the `User` into the `Profile`.

Comment: btw Your `User.__init__()` should be calling `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @quamrana I do not want ```Profile``` to have access to ```User's``` methods and stuff though, just the ```APIConnection``` object it inherited.

And thank you, I have that in my actual code, forgot to update it.

Comment: That's the point of OO and LSP. The `Profile` shouldn't know that it is being passed a `User`. It should assume it has a parameter of an `APIConnection` and act accordingly.

Comment: @quamrana So I should pass ```self``` from inside ```User``` to  ```Profile``` and then use that passed object in profile? I wasn't sure if that would be good practice.

Comment: Why is `User` a subclass of `APIConnection` in the first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in static languages, you could make your `Profile` take a reference to an `APIConnection` and the compiler would enforce the interface.

With python you can have a unit test which passes in an actual `APIConnection` and then any calls to `User` methods would be caught.

As it is you can do this:

```py
class User(APIConnection):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        super().__init__()
        # do login stuff, get access token
        # update inherited session with authorization headers
        self.session.headers.update({"Access-Token": access_token})

        self.profile = Profile(self, profile_data) # set up profile object

class Profile:
    def __init__(self, api, profile_data):
        self.api = api

    def edit_profile(self):
        self.api.api_call()

    def remove_avatar(self):
        self.api.api_call()
```